# Is [] a valid way to represent a null value in a json result?

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, jayrock

I am trying to consume a 3rd party JSON API, and was expected that a null value would have no value at all provided, left out of the result, or some default.  Instead the API returns back [] in place of a single value (not something that would be an array) if the value doesn't exist:

```
"SomeExpectedDate": [],
"SomeExpectedString": [],
...
```

When I try to deserialize this using JayRock JsonConvert, it fails since i'm trying to load into single String or DateTime values.

Is this normal, or should I go complain to the API provider (this is a recently introduced API)

Comment: Why not simply use `null`? BTW `[]` represents an empty array and NOT a null value.

Comment: It's what I did for a JSON parser for Qt.  Not terribly elegant, and in theory `[]` is a legal JSON string, so there is some ambiguity, but some languages don't have a NULL object, and some of those same languages can't tolerate a `null` value in their dictionary objects.  (Note that the proper value for null in a JSON string is the characters "null", without any quotes.)

Comment: But note that an API provider can specify a JSON string the API generates to be anything that's legal JSON, and `"SomeExpectedString": []` is legal JSON.

Comment: Well, it is two fewer characters than `null`, but it is an extremely questionable optimization if that's what it is intended to be.

Comment: @nneonneo -- Not an "optimization", more of an "accommodation" to an environment that does not have a natural representation for a null object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.  In JSON `[]` indicates an empty array.  If you want to represent a null value, use the `null` keyword.  Like:

```
{"someString": null}
```

Although in terms of how you want to *represent* a null value in your JSON, that is entirely up to you.  If you write the receiving code so that it understands that an empty array is equivalent to null, that will certainly work.

In my opinion however that would be a very questionable/unreliable/difficult maintain approach.  It makes a lot more sense to use the `null` keyword, or failing that, an empty string (`{"someString": ""}`).

**Edit:**

To respond to your update about this issue being related to consuming a third-party API, I think definitely this is an issue to take up with the API provider.  They should not be returning `[]` if what they really mean is `null`.  While what they're sending is technically still valid JSON, it's semantically questionable for them to be using `[]` instead of `null`.

Comment: Makes sense.  I've contacted the API provider to see if this was intentional, or a bug.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the third party API you are using says that an empty array is null, then that is perfectly valid and you need to write your code around it.

It is certainly different from anything I've seen before, since json has an actual `null` keyword, but it is perfecly legal syntax.

Comment: The value in question isn't an array, but a single value (string, datetime, etc) that is just returned as [] if its "null".

Comment: @JesseP - But the point is, just because YOU expect a single value doesn't make the empty array invalid.  It's legal JSON, and the API provider can define his API any way he wants.

Comment: But isn't a [] representative of something that should have possibly more than one value?  If it's [] or for instance a single string, all the out of box deserialization (that I know of) in c# can't handle it.  Of the API providider treats an empty value as array, they should give a single value as a 1 element array as well, right?

Comment: @JesseP -- It means whatever they say it means.  You can complain to the API guys but they have the last say -- the JSON spec does not specify what things MEAN.  (But before you go jumping on the API provider make sure that what you're seeing is in the original source string, and not an artifact of the way you parsed it.)

Comment: @JesseP the JSON specification allows ANY value for ANY key. There are no restrictions anywhere that say a value has to have a specific type. Any such restrictions are defined by whoever designed the API, and if they decided there are times when an empty array should be used, then that is what they decided on and it's final. You could ask them why, it seems like an odd choice to me, but ultimately it is a waste of time because they are unlikely to ever change it.